# How to use sapply function (or similar) for a matrix, not a vector?

Tags: r

To speed up the following:

```
x <- c(0, 1, 1.1, 1.5, 1.9, 2.8, 2.9, 3.5)
n <- length(x)
temp <- 0
  for(i in 1:n) {
    for(j in 1:n) {
      temp <- temp + dnorm(x[i] - x[j])
    }
  }

> temp
[1] 13.40157
```

I can simply use the `sapply` function, as below:

```
out <- sapply(x, function(a) dnorm(x - a)))
sum(out)

> sum(out)
[1] 13.40157
```

But how to use the same trick for a `matrix, not vector`, that is I need to speed up the following:

```
x <- matrix(c(3, 3.3, 5, 6, 7, 4), nrow=3, ncol=2, byrow=FALSE)
n <- length(x[,1])

library(mvtnorm) # for dmvnorm
temp <- 0
for(i in 1:n) {
  for(j in 1:n) {
    temp <- temp + dmvnorm(x[i,] - x[j,])
  }
}

> temp
[1] 0.6686979
```

Answer (score 4):

In your 3x3 case, you need to compute the density from the following pairs of rows:

```
1,1
1,2
1,3
2,1
2,2
2,3
3,1
3,2
3,3
```

I would approach this by generating a matrix where each row corresponds the first element in each pair, a matrix where each row corresponds to the second element in each pair, subtract the two, and then pass the result to `dmvnorm`:

```
mat1 <- x[rep(1:n, each=n),]
mat2 <- x[rep(1:n, n),]
sum(dmvnorm(mat1-mat2))
# [1] 0.6686979
```

This appears to be a good deal quicker than the approach using looping:

```
library(mvtnorm)
OP <- function(x) {
  n <- nrow(x)  
  temp <- 0
  for(i in 1:n) {
    for(j in 1:n) {
      temp <- temp + dmvnorm(x[i,] - x[j,])
    }
  }
  return(temp)
}

josilber <- function(x) {
  n <- nrow(x)
  mat1 <- x[rep(1:n, each=n),]
  mat2 <- x[rep(1:n, n),]
  sum(dmvnorm(mat1-mat2))
}

# 100 x 10 matrix
set.seed(144)
x <- matrix(rnorm(1000), nrow=100)
all.equal(OP(x), josilber(x))
# [1] TRUE
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(OP(x), josilber(x))
# Unit: milliseconds
#         expr        min        lq       mean     median         uq       max neval
#        OP(x) 654.553137 696.28275 738.655380 719.058485 760.699813 1194.5594   100
#  josilber(x)   2.775881   2.95865   6.789969   4.346013   5.948481   66.0617   100
```

For this 100 x 10 example, there was more than a 100x speedup from using the vectorized approach.